# Vectorize a loop in Fortran with vector processor

Tags: fortran, cluster-computing, vectorization, intel, gfortran

I'm trying to vectorize the loops in a Fortran program with gfortran and the Intel Xeon CPU.

Previously, the vectorization was implemented by constating

```
!VOCL LOOP,NOVREC
!DIR$ IVDEP
```

which could have worked on a Fujitsu before the loop. But these don't work anymore.

Does anyone have ideas how to vectorize the loop.

Since I'm a newbie for this, it would be perfect if you can show an example to test the result

Here's the code I use to test if it works

```
        PROGRAM VECT_TEST
        IMPLICIT NONE

        INTEGER :: L(10)
        INTEGER :: I

        DO I = 1, 10
          L(I) = I
        END DO

!VOCL LOOP,NOVREC
!DIR$ IVDEP
        DO I = 1, 10
          L(I)=L(I) + 1
        END DO

        END PROGRAM
```

With a test command

```
gfortran vect_test.f -fopt-info-all -O3
```

I got the error output like this

> vect_test.f:18:0: note: ===vect_slp_analyze_bb=== vect_test.f:18:0:
>   note: === vect_analyze_data_refs === vect_test.f:18:0: note: not
>   vectorized: not enough data-refs in basic block.

Comment: You can start here https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/getting-started-with-intel-composer-xe-2013-compiler-pragmas-and-directives https://software.intel.com/sites/default/files/article/301483/simd.upate.pdf

Comment: Yeah I did. Actually I also tried !DIR$ SMID that didn't work either. I'll show the code. Maybe I test it in a wrong way

Comment: Read https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/overview-of-vectorization-reports-and-new-vec-report6

Comment: Thanks Vladimir, I got your idea, I've just updated the post

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your program is useless, the compiler optimizes everything away. If you print the content of the array at the end and make the array larger, it will actually vectorize the loop:

```
PROGRAM VECT_TEST
IMPLICIT NONE

INTEGER :: L(1024)
INTEGER :: I

DO I = 1, 1024
  L(I) = I
END DO

DO I = 1, 1024
  L(I)=L(I) + 1
END DO

PRINT *, L

END PROGRAM
```

compile:

```
gfortran vec.f90 -ftree-vectorizer-verbose=1  -O3

Analyzing loop at vec.f90:13


Vectorizing loop at vec.f90:13

vec.f90:13: note: LOOP VECTORIZED.
Analyzing loop at vec.f90:7


Vectorizing loop at vec.f90:7

vec.f90:7: note: LOOP VECTORIZED.
vec.f90:1: note: vectorized 2 loops in function.
```

Comment: Well okay. This command doesn't print any message on my computer but I got the same result with -fopt-info -O3. Thanks a lot